# Samba server icon on the mac is still the ugly CRT monitor despite the seemingly correct settings

Tags: samba

I configured a Centos 8 server on the network with Samba installed and working great. Because it's used by Mac clients, I added the following to the smb.conf:

```
min protocol = SMB2
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = Macintosh
fruit:posix_rename = yes 
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes 
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
```

Despite the `fruit:model = Macintosh` macOS machines see the ugly icon with a beige/blue CRT monitor, the same icon we see when we browse a Windows PC.

I have a Raspberry PI on the same network with the exact same Samba configuration but the server shows as a beautiful iMac icon in the Finder / Network. I tried various settings for "fruit:model" and none will show anything other than the ugly Windows blue-screen-of-death icon.

Is there something that can be done about this?

Comment: Have you tried `MacSamba` like suggested here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X ?

Comment: @digijay Yes, no difference. On raspberry pi, when I set the fruit:model to MacSamba, we see a question mark icon. On Centos8 server, it's the same old ugly PC icon. Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

```
dnf -y install avahi
systemctl enable --now avahi-daemon.service
systemctl start avahi-daemon
```

also restart Samba:

```
systemctl restart smb
systemctl restart nmb
```

and you're good to go - a beautiful icon will appear instead of the ugly CRT/BDOS icon.